# Have a jQuery powerTip inside of another powerTip?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

### Frameworks

- [jQuery 1.8.3](http://jquery.com/)
- [jQuery PowerTip 1.1.0](http://stevenbenner.github.com/jquery-powertip/)

### Objective

I want to have a `powerTip` inside of another `powerTip`.

### Current Outcome

The first tip (`tip1`) displays fine but the second (`tip2`) doesn't display at all. The CSS for `tip2` works, in that the bottom border shows and all, but when you roll over it the `powerTip` won't show.

### HTML

```
<p>
    Blah blah blah blah blah
    <span data-powertiptarget="tip1">Blah</span>
    and more blah blah blah.
</p>

<div id="tip1" class="tooltip-div">
    <p>
        Email: <a href="mailto:me@somebody.com">me@somebody.com</a><br/>
        <span data-powertiptarget="tip2">Nomenclature</span>: Blah
    </p>
</div>

<div id="tip2" class="tooltip-div">
    Nomenclature: blah blah blah blah.
</div>
```

### CSS

```
.tooltip {
    border-bottom: 1px dashed #333333;
}

.tooltip-div {
    display: none;
}

#powerTip {
    text-align: left;
}

#powerTip a {
    color: #FFFFFF;
}

#powerTip a:visited {
    color: #F0F0F0;
}

#powerTip .tooltip {
    border-bottom: 1px dashed #FFFFFF;
}
```

### JavaScript

```
$('span[data-powertiptarget]').addClass('tooltip');
$('span[data-powertiptarget]').each( function() {
    $(this).powerTip( {
        placement: 'ne',
        mouseOnToPopup: true,
        smartPlacement: true
    });
});
```

Comment: Well that just feels so wrong.. Why would you even want something like that? Things like tooltips should be used only for small additional info display, but not some kind of complex objects...

Comment: @VytautasButkus, quite the contrary. Imagine if you will tool tips for internal nomenclature for an organization. Naturally in language there is nomenclature inside of nomenclature. I want to be able to display tool tips for the nomenclature where ever it may appear, and so that even means inside other tool tips.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The reason why your tooltip doesn't show up is because the contents of each tooltip seem to get copied into a seperate div, and the events attached to it get lost in the process. You can see that quite well e.g. if you inspect the apearing tooltip via the chrome developer tools.

So, what you would need to do is create the powerTip2 instance inside the div#powerTip once the tooltip opens. Also you need unique ids for every opened tooltip.

[Example on JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2Xjb8/)

Code:

```
$('span[data-powertiptarget]').addClass('tooltip');
createPowerTips($('span[data-powertiptarget]'),'powerTip');

function createPowerTips($elems, popupId) {
    $elems.each( function() {
        $(this).powerTip( {
            popupId: popupId,
            placement: 'ne',
            mouseOnToPopup: true,
            smartPlacement: true
        }).on({
            powerTipOpen: function() {
                createPowerTips(
                    $('#powerTip').find('span[data-powertiptarget]'),
                    'powerTip2'
                );
            }
        });
    });
}
```

As you can see in the example, the nested tooltip has no CSS attached to it. So you'd have to copy all the #powerTip CSS over for #powerTip2

Clearly, the plugin has not been designed for such a use case.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use qTip instead?

A similar example: [Tooltip on tooltip](http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip/demos/effects/multitooltip)

Also, please note that [qTip v2](http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip2/) is present.